# CakePHP - conditions on associated model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

> Problem in short: I want to set
>   conditions on an associated model. How
>   do I do it?

I'm having a problem with the associations in my CakePHP application.

The associations looks like this:

```
Event has many EventSum belongs to Account has many AccountUser belongs to User
Event has many EventDebt ... (the rest is the same as above)
Event also belongs to User
```

The application is a private econonmy program in PHP and uses the CakePHP framework.

An **Event** is a financial event, a purchase, transaction between accounts etc. It only holds information about date, title and user.

An **EventSum** holds information about an **Account** and how much to debit or credit (in one column, just positive or negative).

**Account** holds information about title of the account.

**AccountUser** holds an id of an **Account** and a **User**. This indicates that

---

So, now I want to fetch **Events** based on what accounts a **User** is associated to. How can I do this?

I want to fetch the following info:
Event, together with the EventSum. The Events are fetched from Accounts where the User has access.

Thanks for any help,
/Magnus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to be able to query your `Event` class with the following conditions:

```
'Account.user_id =' => $userId
```

Is my assumption correct?

When doing queries which require conditions on associated models, you can use either the `Containable` behaviour (comes with [CakePHP 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable)) or the 'Linkable' behaviour (which can be found [here](https://github.com/Terr/Linkable)).

What happens when you try this (be sure to attach the `Containable` behaviour to your models first):

```
$condition = array('Account.user_id =' => $userId);
$contain = array('EventSum' => array('Account'), 'EventDebt' => array('Account'));
$result = $this->Event->find('all', compact('condition', 'contain'));
```

Note that you might experience issues when 'containing' both `EventSum` and `EventDebt` if both of their associations to `Account` use the same alias name.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I solved it on my own with Containable behavior. Therefor your answer has been marked as correct. Thanks for your reply.